# Wrapping anchor text by space (not word break)

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I want the text in my HTML href to wrap around to the next line as if was just regular text. [Here is how I want the text to wrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl7Pl.png).

[And here's how it's currently wrapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1qI9.png).

This is my code:

```html
<p>I'm currently studying at the{' '}
<a href="url1">University</a>, working as an AI Research Intern at the <a href="url2">Lab</a> where I work on the end-to-end data pipeline for the AI-Powered Lifecycle Financial Planning project.</p>
```

I tried some of the suggested solutions including using `overflow-wrap: break-word;` which yielded [this result instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IriVM.png). If I have posted this in the wrong place or this question has been asked already, I apologize.

[The parent CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe91I.png)

Comment: if <a> is `display-inline;` it does.

Comment: The parent div of the text is `display: grid` because I am also including an image to the side. Does this prevent the text from wrapping?

Comment: @RustomIchhaporia i sudjest to put the whole element code in the answer ( with this i mean also the parent with its css ) for let us have a better and clear vision of the situation :)

Comment: Does the snippet reproduce your issue or looks alike your screenshot ? if not, then there is parts of your code missing. .. okay, there is some grid involved, what else ?

Comment: I've added the parent to my question. The HTML I've pasted is simply surrounded by that class.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you would like to have the word to break. I mean that usually a word wraps when it doesn't fully fit in the remaining space of the parent element, you can override this behaviour ( so breaking a word in 'half' ) that are displayed on separate lines by adding to the parent this property

```
.my_parent_element{
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```css
div{
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>I'm currently studying at the{' '}
<a href="url1">University of Ciicy-University</a>, working as an AI Research Intern at the <a href="url2">Lab</a> where I work on the end-to-end data pipeline for the AI-Powered Lifecycle Financial Planning project.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I added `word-wrap: break-word` to the parent element of the text (and to the div specifier inside it) and neither changed the result of the wrapping.